# Swift: Found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm aware of why this error occurs but I'm having trouble finding a solution here. Basically I'm trying to get a thumbnail of someones avatar from the address book. I get the data and then need to check the data is not nil (in other words we successfully got an image). If we have it then I return it as a UIImage. The code works well in objective-c. The ported code crashes with the `found nil while unwrapping an optional value` error on the `data = ABPerson...`.

```
    var data :NSData? = NSData()

    var ref :ABRecordRef? = delegate.localContacts.objectForKey(email)

    if ref != nil {
        data = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(ref, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue()
    }

    if data?.length > 0 {
            return UIImage(data: data!)!
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat` returns an unsafe pointer of type `Unmanaged<CFData>!`. You have to test it.

```
if let ref = ref {
    let img = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(ref, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)
    if img != nil {
        data = img.takeRetainedValue()
    }
}
```